# How to multiply vector and matrix expressions involving transposes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do i expand and simplify the vector expression
$(\vec{a}-\vec{b})^T.(\vec{a}-\vec{b})$ = ?
And if there are matrices A and B instead of vectors a and b, how do i multiply and simplify this expression?
$(A-B)^T.(A-B)$ = ?
Also in the normal equations for solving least squares problems, we have expressions of the type
$(Ax-b)^T.(Ax-b)$ = ?

I know that is really basic. Sorry but my basics are rusty. In fact, I need to so some matrix calculus next. Please do point me to some relevant links.

Comment: $(A+B)^T = A^T + B^T$. Then just expand and distribute the normal way...

Comment: @Rahul.Thanks. can you give me some links having all these basic identities involving vectors and matrices? Like a'b+ba'=? and so on.

Comment: Try this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Properties

Comment: @Rahul.Thanks again. I should have googled for "matrix transpose properties".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful source of useful identities (most of which aren't proved though) is [the matrix cookbook](http://matrixcookbook.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Just think of a vector as a matrix of one column, and all the matrix rules apply.